# JQueryMobile Back to Previous Page

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a JQM page with some events on html elements that will change DOM of the page. e.g. clicking a button will add a `paragraph` on the page. The page also have a link that will load another page via ajax. The new page have back button, but the problem is that when the back button is triggered, it will go to the previous page with the original content. What I want is to retain the modified DOM of the page. How can I do this with JQM?

Thanks.

Comment: How are you going back? If you are using history.go(-1) or history.back or `data-rel="back"` links, the browser should preserve your page with new DOM content.

Comment: im using data-rel="back" in a link

Comment: Would you be able to put up a sample jsfiddle with your issue?